# Не удается отправить команду rcon маинкрафт с помощью python, как исправить?

Tags: python

```
with MCRcon(ip, password, port) as mcr:
    resp = mcr.command('list')
    mcr.connect()
    mcr.disconnect()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botg.py", line 76, in <module>
    resp = mcr.command(str(text))
  File "C:\Users\Vova2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mcrcon.py", line 114, in command
    result = self._send(2, command)
  File "C:\Users\Vova2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mcrcon.py", line 95, in _send
    (in_length,) = struct.unpack("<i", self._read(4))
  File "C:\Users\Vova2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mcrcon.py", line 77, in _read
    data += self.socket.recv(length - len(data))
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

Comment: Ну, во-первых, приведён стектрейс от какого-то другого кода. А во-вторых, разве команды куда-либо не должны отправляться **после** соединения (`connect`)?

Answer (score 0):

Выполните сначала коннект, а потом уже отправляйте комманды

```
with MCRcon(ip, password, port) as mcr:
    mcr.connect()
    resp = mcr.command('list')
    print(resp)
    mcr.disconnect()
```

[Ссылка](https://pypi.org/project/mcrcon/) на документацию